# Wedge product of one-forms

Tags: differential-geometry

I want to check my hand calculations of wedge products of 1-forms such as

```
yz dx and sin(z) dx
```

I see that

```
Wedge
```

has no built-in meaning. Should I try to define

```
Wedge
```

myself?

I want to use symbols to refer to 1-forms, perhaps a list

```
phi = {y*z, 0, x}
psi = {z, x, 0}
```

for yz dx + x dz and z dx+x dy respectively.

Then I want to manipulate them using the operator

```
Wedge[phi,psi]
```

Comment: It is safe to define `Wegde`, if that's what you're asking (unclear what the question is).  It has not built-in meaning.

Comment: Your question may be put [on-hold](https://goo.gl/jXYaiD) because it's not clear what you need. To avoid or revert the Hold you can [edit] your question to [improve it](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3) and make it specific, well structured and easy to understand. Please don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your questions are and will be most welcomed. Learn about [good questions here](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3).

Comment: Have you tried the array-based approach of TensorWedge[phi, psi] ? This is a representation of the algebraic part of exterior calculus, but not the differential part.

Comment: Another possibility is to use an external package for full exterior calculus, like http://www.xact.es/xTerior/ , where Wedge does have the meaning you need. See examples in the xTeriorDoc.nb file in that page.